# ASp.net Identity How to use the same dbcontext for EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use the same DbContext for ASP.NET Identity and my other work - otherwise bad things happen. Unfortunately, I am not able to achieve this - I end up using two DbContexts, which are causing doubled objects etc.

I am not sure what code is  needed to debug this...ask if I missed something.

Startup:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(PriorityDBContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    }
}
```

PriorityDBContext

```
public class PriorityDBContext : ApplicationDbContext
    {
        public PriorityDBContext()
            : base()
        {
        }

// seems to be called twice :(
        public static new ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new PriorityDBContext() as ApplicationDbContext;
        }

 // snipped my DbSets
    }
}
```

The ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("EFDBContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

And in my main controller:

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{

    var httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    ApplicationDbContext pbContext httpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();

    this.UserManager = httpContext.Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    this.uoW = new UnitOfWork(pbContext);

    return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
}
```

Comment: Just move everything from your **PriorityDBContext** to the **ApplicationDbContext**. With that change you have only one EF database context and should be able to use the same database for Identity and your other stuff.

Comment: @Horizon_Net The bug was elsewhere (see my answer, basically had not seen a quite obvious line) but you are certainly correct, that that would be a possible improvement of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind - the error was quite obvious and basically a result of leftovers from the original state.
My Unit of Work initialization looked like this:

```
/// </summary>
private PriorityDBContext dbContext = new PriorityDBContext();

public UnitOfWork()
{ 
}

public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    this.dbContext = (PriorityDBContext)ApplicationDbContext;
}
```

a new PriorityDbContext was created for each new Unit of Work. The dbContext passed into the Constructor was never used.

Now it looks like this:

```
    private PriorityDBContext dbContext = null;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        PriorityDBContext dbContext = new PriorityDBContext();
    }

    public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext as PriorityDBContext;
    }
```

Problem solved ;)